# Swift example by apple explained

Tags: swift

Im following the [swift programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID124)
So far i've understood everything untill the following line, where they create a board for a game.

```
let finalSquare = 25
var board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
```

for what I understand is:

```
// Create a constant with the value of 25
let finalSquare = 25

// This part will create a array with int values.
var board = [Int]
```

The part I dont understand :

```
 (count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Could someone explain what this code does ? I know the result is an array with Int's 0 but i dont understand how they create the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code is identical to:

```
var board = Array<Int>(count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
```

The `[Int]` syntax is preferred over `Array<Int>`, but they mean the same thing.

Array has an `init` that looks like this:

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)
```

So this is just calling that initializer, and that initializer creates an array that has `finalSquare+1` 0s.

Comment: How should I interpret 'count: ' and ''repeatedValue: ' ? why is it not just [Int](finalsquare+1,  0).

Comment: @Shmidt I know but normaly you only give the parameter names at a function declaration not at a function call right ?

Comment: @SvenB it's not parameter name, but named parameter. Difference is that there is additional name to show what is this parameter. If function was like you wrote, then later you'll need to remember, what was first and second parameters. Also, it's not obvious, so you can occasionally switch them or use something else. Named parameters is easy readable and that's why error prone way.